# Eclipse Java IDE crashing on startup after update

Tags: 22.04, java, eclipse

A couple of days ago I updated everything on my computer, and today, when I tried to open Eclipse, it crashed on startup and gave me this message:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file /home/pablordgz/.var/app/org.eclipse.Java/eclipse/configuration/(lognumber).log
```

I tried changing the JDK version, changing the VM directory in `eclipse.ini` (which resulted in Eclipse not detecting the JVM), and uninstalling and installing Eclipse, but nothing seemed to work.

The log doesn't tell me much because it's over 1k lines long, but here it is in case you find it helpful. This is only about a third of it since it triples the character limit:

```
!SESSION 2024-03-14 21:20:48.244 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.31.0.20240307-1200
java.version=17.0.10
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:48.774
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2006)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:267)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle was updated. The framework must be restarted to finalize the configuration change
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start(Activator.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:825)
    ... 27 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle was updated. The framework must be restarted to finalize the configuration change
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start(Activator.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2006)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:267)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1432)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.jreinfo.ui 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.000
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.oomph.jreinfo.ui [299]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.24.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.questionnaire 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.002
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.questionnaire [319]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.24.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.userstorage 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.004
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.userstorage [378]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.userstorage.oauth 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.006
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.userstorage.oauth [379]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime; version="3.3.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.userstorage.ui 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.008
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.userstorage.ui [380]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.userstorage.internal
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.userstorage.internal; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.userstorage"; bundle-version="1.2.0.v20210517-0327"; version="1.1.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.userstorage.tests,  org.eclipse.userstorage.oauth,  org.eclipse.userstorage.ui,  org.eclipse.userstorage.sdk"; uses:="org.apache.http.client.fluent,  org.apache.http"
       org.eclipse.userstorage [378]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.core 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.009
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wst.common.core [382]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.15.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.emf 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.010
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wst.common.emf [383]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi; bundle-version="[2.4.0,3.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.012
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit [493]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.9.0,4.0.0)"; x-installation:="greedy"; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.emf.ecore; bundle-version="[2.33.0,3.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.013
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui [496]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.9.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.p2.edit 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.014
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.oomph.p2.edit [591]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.24.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.workingsets.edit 4 0 2024-03-14 21:20:49.015
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.oomph.workingsets.edit [602]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.24.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2064)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1967)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1883)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)
```